# Is there a way to make multiple IndexedVertexLists refer to the same vertices while having different lists of indices

Tags: python, pyglet

I want to have two (or more) IndexedVertexLists which refer to the same vertices while having different lists of indices. The problem I am having is that, if I were to create two (or more) IndexedVertexLists with the same vertices, it would take up twice the amount of the GPU's memory compared to what it actually needs.

What I mean:

```
import pyglet


vertices = [
        0, 0,
        0, 0.5,
        0.5, 0,
        0.5, 0.5
]

indices1 = [0, 1, 2]
indices2 = [0, 2, 3]

vertex_list_indexed_1 = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list_indexed(4, indices1, ('v2f', vertices))
vertex_list_indexed_2 = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list_indexed(4, indices2, ('v2f', vertices))
```

What I want would be something like this (this does not work, obviously):

```
import pyglet


vertices = [
        0, 0,
        0, 0.5,
        0.5, 0,
        0.5, 0.5
]

indices1 = [0, 1, 2]
indices2 = [0, 2, 3]

vertex_list  = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(4, ('v2f', vertices))

vertex_list_indexed_1 = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list_indexed(4, indices1, vertex_list)
vertex_list_indexed_2 = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list_indexed(4, indices2, vertex_list)
```

I couldn't find anything in the [pyglet documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that would solve my problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue, aren't lists passed-by-reference? Which would mean you could create one list and pass it along and it would be shared? Or is perhaps Pyglet's internal structure copying and there for not passing the reference?

Comment: Pyglet copies the entire `vertex_list` into the GPU's memory every time `vertex_list_indexed()` is called.

Comment: Have you found a solution, man? I have the same problem, can't get it to work.